# How to get the Version of an event appended to a stream

Tags: c#, eventstoredb

I am writing to an EventStore stream using the C# API AppendToStreamAsync() call. I see that while this returns a WriteResult, the version of the newly appended event isn't returned. I can't rely on NextExpectedVersion as there are potentially multiple clients writing to this stream.

I could subscribe to the stream and wait for "my" event to turn up, 
but have I missed something else, the [documentation](http://docs.geteventstore.com/dotnet-api/3.9.0/writing-to-a-stream/) is pretty light and doesn't even mention the returned type.

What is regarded as the best way to get this number?

Comment: I just start looking at EventStore and applying this in separate branch. Still can't find an answer - is it safe to assume WriteResult.NextExpectedVersion is effectively represent an Event.EventNumber of new event? I did several concurrent tests and it looks consistent, but still no information like this in official  docs

Answer (score 0):

The version is not needed, because before you write the stream you know the version of your aggregate (stream), so when the write is successful you known the version.

Before you write a new event to a stream you have to read the stream to rehydrate the aggregate. Then you know the version. Because when an other writer has written to the same stream you must first have the new state. (If you stil have the aggregate in memory, you can query from the current version in your aggregate)

If the optimistic locking is not needed you can give the ANY version when writing the stream. (This can be done when the stream is just a logging stream)

Comment: You don't always know the # of events in your stream because you may use streams for other things than aggregates.